# How should I set up OAuth consent screen without Android app verification?

Tags: android, google-api, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I am working on an Android application which makes the use of Google Fit API. I have enabled it on [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com) which provides the Client id and API key.
How should I set up the OAuth screen? 
My application uses the Sessions API for recording data and History API for viewing previously stored data. Currently, I am able to record the activity data which can be viewed in the Google Fit App but I am getting this error when I use the History API

```
com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 5000: Application needs OAuth consent from the user
```

I want to check the functionalities of the API just for demonstration, so no verification should be required for the app. How should I set up the consent screen or ask for user consent? 
 Do I require the verification for sensitive scopes like Activity Reading and Writing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check you are requesting the correct scopes with associated Read/Write permissions:
   https://developers.google.com/fit/android/api-client-example

```
val fitnessOptions = FitnessOptions.builder()
    .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
    .addDataType(DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
    .build()
```

2. Check you are not attempting to read from scopes your don't have access to:

i.e. change the data type `DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA` below in the response

```
private fun accessGoogleFit() {
    val end = LocalDateTime.now()
    val start = end.minusYears(1)
    val endSeconds = end.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toEpochSecond()
    val startSeconds = start.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toEpochSecond()

    val readRequest = DataReadRequest.Builder()
        .aggregate(DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
        .setTimeRange(startSeconds, endSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
        .build()
    val account = GoogleSignIn.getAccountForExtension(this, fitnessOptions)
    Fitness.getHistoryClient(this, account)
        .readData(readRequest)
        .addOnSuccessListener({ response ->
            // Use response data here
            Log.i(TAG, "OnSuccess()")
        })
        .addOnFailureListener({ e -> Log.d(TAG, "OnFailure()", e) })
}
```